# "Incorrect JSON format"

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am making a `POST` request with required **body** parameters, testing this `POST` request in `POSTMAN` gives me correct response, but when I am passing same body parameters from my code I am getting below error-:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
```

**Code -:**

```
     func submitStudentAttendance(url:String,id:String,SessionID: Int,SchoolID:Int,BatchID:Int,ClassID:Int,SectionID:Int,Medium:Int,Date:String,accessToken:String) {
            let params : [String:Any] = [
                "$id":"1",
                "SchoolID":1,
                "SessionID":42,
                "BatchID":106,
                "ClassID":634,
                "SectionID":1246,
                "Medium":"English",
                "Date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "CreatedBy":118,
                "CreatedOn":"2019-04-14T17:02:34",
                "studentList":"",
                "AttendenceData":"[{\"ID\":0,\"SchoolID\":null,\"SessionID\":null,\"ClassID\":634,\"SectionID\":1246,\"StudID\":\"DSM00399\",\"SubjectID\":null,\"Date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"Attendence\":\"P\",\"CreatedOn\":null,\"CreatedBy\":0,\"IsActive\":null,\"Remarks\":\"rem16\",\"timeID\":null,\"AtndType\":null,\"BatchID\":null,\"Medium\":null}]"
]

            let urlRequest = NSURL(string: url)
            var request = URLRequest(url: urlRequest! as URL)
            let tokenString = "Bearer " + accessToken
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue(tokenString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])

            let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            if let json = json {
                print(json)
            }
            request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);

            let alamoRequest = Alamofire.request(request as URLRequestConvertible)
            alamoRequest.responseString {

                response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if response.data != nil {
                        do{
                            let json =  try JSON(data: response.data!)
                            print(json)
                        }catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

The body part is exactly same as in `POSTMAN`, but still not working. Can anyone let me know what's going wrong here? Is this server side issue or I am sending body request in wrong format?

**POSTMAN RESPONSE** -:

[image]

Comment: this is server side issue it clearly state that the value which you get is not in correct json format. did not do the downvote

Comment: You don't need to convert your `Data` to `NSString` and eventually to `Data` when providing it as the `request.httpBody`. And use `Dictionary` type instead of `String` for the value of `"AttendenceData"` key.

Answer (score 1):

When the params as declared in your question is converted into JSON, it looks like this. Here, AttendanceData value is not converted as proper JSON structure. It looks like a string.

**JSON from your param:**

```
{
  "Date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "CreatedBy": 118,
  "$id": "1",
  "BatchID": 106,
  "ClassID": 634,
  "Medium": "English",
  "studentList": "",
  "SchoolID": 1,
  "SectionID": 1246,
  "AttendenceData": "[{\"ID\":0,\"SchoolID\":null,\"SessionID\":null,\"ClassID\":634,\"SectionID\":1246,\"StudID\":\"DSM00399\",\"SubjectID\":null,\"Date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"Attendence\":\"P\",\"CreatedOn\":null,\"CreatedBy\":0,\"IsActive\":null,\"Remarks\":\"rem16\",\"timeID\":null,\"AtndType\":null,\"BatchID\":null,\"Medium\":null}]",
  "CreatedOn": "2019-04-14T17:02:34",
  "SessionID": 42
}
```

But if you declare param as shown below, and converted to JSON, AttendanceData value is properly converted to JSON.

```
let params : [String:Any] = [
    "$id":"1",
    "SchoolID":1,
    "SessionID":42,
    "BatchID":106,
    "ClassID":634,
    "SectionID":1246,
    "Medium":"English",
    "Date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "CreatedBy":118,
    "CreatedOn":"2019-04-14T17:02:34",
    "studentList":"",
    "AttendenceData":[
        "ID":0,"SchoolID":"null","SessionID":"null","ClassID":634,"SectionID":1246,"StudID":"DSM00399","SubjectID":"null","Date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Attendence":"P","CreatedOn":"null","CreatedBy":0,"IsActive":"null","Remarks":"rem16","timeID":"null","AtndType":"null","BatchID":"null","Medium":"null"
    ]
]
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "BatchID": 106,
  "CreatedBy": 118,
  "ClassID": 634,
  "studentList": "",
  "SectionID": 1246,
  "SessionID": 42,
  "AttendenceData": {
    "IsActive": "null",
    "AtndType": "null",
    "SectionID": 1246,
    "timeID": "null",
    "SessionID": "null",
    "Attendence": "P",
    "Date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Remarks": "rem16",
    "Medium": "null",
    "SchoolID": "null",
    "BatchID": "null",
    "ClassID": 634,
    "StudID": "DSM00399",
    "SubjectID": "null",
    "CreatedBy": 0,
    "ID": 0,
    "CreatedOn": "null"
  },
  "Date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "CreatedOn": "2019-04-14T17:02:34",
  "Medium": "English",
  "SchoolID": 1
}
```

Hope it could also solve your problem.

Comment: Can you assign the json data from "let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])" directly to request.httpBody instead of converting it to string and then back to data?

Comment: you mean request.httpbody = data ?

Comment: Yes. Just a thought

Comment: "let json =  try JSON(data: response.data!)". Can you share this code? I don't understand how this actually converts the data to JSON.

Comment: it's an issue with response data, because the call goes inside .Success case, and method with try throws an error.